# H2 Database and oracle mode - alter table only with different sql statement - Flyway migration test

Tags: java, sql, oracle, h2

### Setup

We use Flyway for data migration and want to test our SQL scripts with JUnit.

- target (production) environment runs on **oracle** while
- developer machines runs a **h2** database (version: 1.4.196)

Runs fine for the most scripts but seems some SQL statements are not working for h2 and Oracle

- current Oracle: `alter table mytable modify (status not null);`
- correct h2    : `alter table mytable ALTER COLUMN status SET NOT NULL`

If I run this oracle style locally on my h2 database I got the following exception: `Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE MYTABLE MODIFY ([*]STATUS NOT NULL) "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
alter table mytable modify (status not null) [42001-196]`

### What I tried

According to http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility I already configured the h2 database for oracle mode: `url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=Oracle`

### Question

- Is there something that I could to get the Oracle statement running on h2 db?
- Or does this SQL alter statement belong to this case mentioned at h2 website?

  > and tries to be compatible with other databases

### Update

I filed a github issue and got to know that issue will be solved with next h2 db release: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/689

Comment: Since you're only modifying one column have you tried not to use the `(..)`. Meaning what happens if you write `alter table mytable modify status not null;`?

Comment: And have you tried to declare the datatype of column `status`?

Comment: I tried without brackets but than I got: `Unknown data type: "NOT"; SQL statement: alter table mytable modify status not null [50004-196]`.
What do you mean with declare datatype `status`? Status is already there in the table (without the not null constraint yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are modifying only one column of a table you can write the `ALTER TABLE` statement like this

```
ALTER TABLE mytable 
MODIFY status VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL;
```

This example assumes that the column `status` datatype is a `VARCHAR2(50)`. Please make sure you use the datatype in your `ALTER TABLE` statement. You should use the current datatype of column `status` unless you want to migrate the datatype too.

Furthermore it does not use the `(...)` which is a Oracle specific shortcut for changing multiple column of the same table.

```
alter table
   table_name
modify
   (
       column1_name  column1_datatype,
       column2_name  column2_datatype,
       column3_name  column3_datatype,
       column4_name  column4_datatype
   );
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with this statement. Only problem is to tell every developer to write modify statements in this way that h2 and Oracle does understand. Furthermore you need to check first the current data types for the column even if you are not interested in changing them. Maybe I will leave out the automatic test for local machines but have them running for continous integration with OracleDB. Last hope would be that with future updates of h2 it will be possible in future. Thanks so far.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. It obviously works on Oracle modifying a column and omitting the datatype. That is a nice shortcut but not best pratice. Write explicit DML and express what you want to do.

Comment: for me it is more expressive to tell what I am going to change (only the not null) instead of telling the type again. When I read the alter statement with not null and type I can not see directly that I am not going to change the type. But this is just a personal view :)